# Russian characters converting to binary incorrectly (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, binary

I'm writing a program in JavaScript that needs to convert text to 8-bit binary, which I accomplish with a loop that uses "exampleVariable.charCodeAt(i).toString(2)", then appends "0"s to the front until the length of the binary representation of each character is 8 bits. However, when Russian characters are passed into the function, each character is converted to an 11-bit binary representation, when it should actually be 16 bits. For example, "д" converts to 10000110100, when, in actuality, it should convert to "1101000010110100". Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: JavaScript strings use UTF-16 - each character is 16 bits, not 8.

Comment: When I convert "a" to binary, the result is "01100001". That's what I mean by 8-bit, I guess.

Comment: So what character encoding are you trying to get? UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, except that Russian characters are represented by 16 bits...I think. (In case you haven't noticed, I don't know a whole lot about this).

Comment: Russian characters fit in the UTF-16 16-bit space, but for UTF-8 they need a prefix byte (as you wrote in the question). You have to perform that conversion yourself by [following the rules for UTF-8 character encoding.](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/from-utf-16-to-utf-8-in-javascript/)

Comment: It looks to me like `10000110100` is the correct binary representation of the Cyrillic Unicode codepoint for д (0x0434). The longer binary you listed "1101000010110100" is codepoint (0xd0b4) which is part of the Hangul symbols.

Comment: AHHH, thanks. So I would then convert the outputs of this function to their 8-bit binary equivalents?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to get the binary representation of the UTF-8 representation of the character. JavaScript uses UTF-16 internally, so you will have to do some work to do the translation. There are various libraries out there, we'd need to know more about the environment to recommend the right tools. If you wanted to code it up yourself, it would be roughly:

```
function codepointToUTF_8(code) {
    if (code < 0x07f) {
        return [code];
    } else if (code < 0x800) {
        var byte1 = 0xc0 | (code >> 6  );
        var byte2 = 0x80 | (code & 0x3f);
        return [ byte1, byte2 ];
    } else if (code < 0x10000) {
        var byte1 = 0xe0 | ( code >> 12        );
        var byte2 = 0x80 | ((code >> 6 ) & 0x3f);
        var byte3 = 0x80 | ( code        & 0x3f);
        return [ byte1, byte2, byte3 ];
    } else {
        var byte1 = 0xf0 | ( code >> 18        );
        var byte2 = 0x80 | ((code >> 12) & 0x3f);
        var byte3 = 0x80 | ((code >>  6) & 0x3f);
        var byte4 = 0x80 | ( code        & 0x3f);
        return [ byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4 ];
    }
}

function strToUTF_8 (str) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        // NOTE: this will not handle anything beyond the BMP    
        result.push(codepointToUTF_8(str.charCodeAt(i)));
    }
    console.log('result = ', result);
    return [].concat.apply([], result);
}


function  byteToBinary (b) {
    var str = b.toString(2);
    while (str.length < 8) {
        str = '0' + str;
    }
    return str;
}

function toBinaryUTF_8 (str) {
    return strToUTF_8(str).map(byteToBinary).join(' ');
}

console.log("абвгд => '" + toBinaryUTF_8("абвгд") + "'");
```

When I execute this I get:

```
абвгд => '11010000 10110000 11010000 10110001 11010000 10110010 11010000 10110011 11010000 10110100'
```

I haven't tested this thoroughly, but it should handle the Russian characters OK. It produces an array of character codes, which if you translate as you were trying before with 8 binary bits per character, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks mate! I think this is exactly what I need :D.

Comment: So maybe I'm just a n00b, but...I can't get the conversion from UTF-8 numbers to binary to work...What should I do to the numbers to convert them to binary? .charCodeAt(i).toString(2) isn't working because the numbers are no longer in string form. (I'm new-er to JavaScript...can you tell?).

Comment: I added a bit more code to show how to use the conversion functionality. Hope that helps...

Comment: Ohh, now I see how it works. Thanks mate, you've been really helpful! :D. It's OK if I just use this code (with only minor changes to prevent possible variable name collisions)?

Comment: go for it - copy away

Comment: Thanks mate! And it automatically appends '0's so that the characters are converted to 8-bit binary (.charAt(0).toString(2) returns 7 or -6 bit values). Thanks again! :D Really helpful.

Comment: So I don't want to sound picky, but I'm just curious about something: this converts Chinese characters to 32 bits per character, but other converters convert them to 24 bits...is there something I could add to fix this? It's fairly important that any input of any language gets converted to an accurate binary representation...Just curious. Thanks mate.

Comment: Yup, there was a bug in the code. It was selecting the 4-byte representation for any code points above 0x1000, while it should have been 0x10000. I've edited the code, so it should be (more) correct now. I did a quick check and Han characters now come out as 3 bytes.